# Run two operating systems on the same computer at the same time (no hosting)

Tags: motherboard, multi-boot, operating-systems

I know that two operating systems can share the same computer through hosting. For example, WINE can host Windows, or vice versa, Virtual Box can host a Linux system on a Windows box, but in both cases only one operating system is actually controlling the motherboard and is providing interfaces to the hosted OS.

**Is it possible to configure a system to actually share a motherboard between two operating systems?**

For this to work, the motherboard would probably have to have two CPUs and also some way to split the memory. Also, you would probably need two video cards and a way of dedicating peripheral slots to one OS or the other.

Comment: So you don't mind a double of everything but the motherboard huh

Comment: I know of zero computers that have the capability to POST into multiple operating systems simultaneously.  You do understand that after a system does a POST, it attempts to find the boot storage device, if you have multiple storage devices that can boot, you still have a primary boot storage device that allows you to chain load those devices.  *I don't agree that a mainframe can boot to multiple operating systems, and run those operating systems, simultaneously.*  I say that, with a good amount of knowlege, on an IBM mainframe.

Answer (score 5):

The hardware would have to specifically support it. A normal PC cannot do this. A mainframe can do it via logical partitions. I think this qualifies as there is no real separate operating system running underneath the LPARs. (Note mainframes also use "hosting" but here there is a single OS running on the hardware like z/VM.

Back in the day if you had a PC card in your Mac you could run both operating systems at once. Would you count this as hosting? I think I probably would...

I am sure there are other examples but the mainframe is the only one I can think of right now that qualifies.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing to what you are asking is generally referred to as a type-1 Hypervisor. However Hypervisor is really a "minimal OS" (if it even qualifies as an OS) host for multiple guest OS. A sort of supervising kernel.

You can typically dedicate single CPUs in a multi-CPU setup to a specific guest, and allocate memory and storage space for each guest.

Neither guest OS (the only interactive bits in the scenario) relies on the other to operate: the part you find objectionable in your question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor

I think ESXi is the vmware type 1 hypervisor, and can run on e.g. a Dell Poweredge. My office runs a few servers (phones, storage) on a single powedge bought used on ebay for about 250$. I did not set it up, but I helped.

Comment: You are not wrong, so this is not disagreement as it is a subjective issue and depends what we consider an "OS". But in this case I would say ESXi is the single operating system that controls the hardware and the other's are guests so this is definitely not an instance of 2 operating systems running directly on the hardware. The mainframe LPAR is definitely closer than ESXi.

Comment: oh, I agree, I said that in the second sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, no. Most of the interconnects within a motherboards circuitry are buses, and the operation of a bus MUST be coordinated by a single arbiter. Interrupts could not function effectively.

In order to do this, you would need a custom motherboard that implemented pretty much the entirety of its functionality twice, with special circuitry to allow two southbridges to share a physical bus, dedicated memory slots per CPU (for parallel northbridge operations), etc.